# Проблема с выводом hreflang на prestashop (Smarty) - нужна генерация/вывод ссылки на текущую страницу

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

Привет. Я сам не программист, а SEO, и в коде пока разбираюсь не на высшем уровне, поэтому уперся в такую проблему.
Надо на prestashop сделать мультиязычную разметку hreflang. Заметил, что базовый модуль prestashop "Блок выбора языка" уже практически под это заточен.
Я немного подправил и получил:

```
        {foreach from=$languages key=k item=language name="languages"}
        {if $language.iso_code != $lang_iso}
            {assign var=indice_lang value=$language.id_lang}
            {if isset($lang_rewrite_urls.$indice_lang)}
                <link href="{$lang_rewrite_urls.$indice_lang|escape:htmlall}" rel="alternate" hreflang="{$language.iso_code|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
            {else}
                <link href="{$link->getLanguageLink($language.id_lang)|escape:htmlall}" rel="alternate" hreflang="{$language.iso_code|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
            {/if}
        {/if}
        {if $language.iso_code != $lang_iso}
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
```

НО! проблема заключается в том, что я не учел то, что в функции сделано так, что бы первая строчка не генерировалась ссылка (не было вывода ссылки на текущую страницу, дабы страница не ссылалась сама на себя - для поисковых роботов).

```
<link href="{$lang_rewrite_urls.$indice_lang|escape:htmlall}" rel="alternate" hreflang="{$language.iso_code|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
```

также есть php, но там параметров изменения генерации я не вижу (либо там их нет, либо я их еще не знаю)

```
protected function _prepareHook($params)
{
    $languages = Language::getLanguages(true, $this->context->shop->id);
    if (!count($languages))
        return false;
    $link = new Link();

    if ((int)Configuration::get('PS_REWRITING_SETTINGS'))
    {
        $default_rewrite = array();
        if (Dispatcher::getInstance()->getController() == 'product' && ($id_product = (int)Tools::getValue('id_product')))
        {
            $rewrite_infos = Product::getUrlRewriteInformations((int)$id_product);
            foreach ($rewrite_infos as $infos)
                $default_rewrite[$infos['id_lang']] = $link->getProductLink((int)$id_product, $infos['link_rewrite'], $infos['category_rewrite'], $infos['ean13'], (int)$infos['id_lang']);
        }

        if (Dispatcher::getInstance()->getController() == 'category' && ($id_category = (int)Tools::getValue('id_category')))
        {
            $rewrite_infos = Category::getUrlRewriteInformations((int)$id_category);
            foreach ($rewrite_infos as $infos)
                $default_rewrite[$infos['id_lang']] = $link->getCategoryLink((int)$id_category, $infos['link_rewrite'], $infos['id_lang']);
        }

        if (Dispatcher::getInstance()->getController() == 'cms' && (($id_cms = (int)Tools::getValue('id_cms')) || ($id_cms_category = (int)Tools::getValue('id_cms_category'))))
        {
            $rewrite_infos = (isset($id_cms) && !isset($id_cms_category)) ? CMS::getUrlRewriteInformations($id_cms) : CMSCategory::getUrlRewriteInformations($id_cms_category);
            foreach ($rewrite_infos as $infos)
            {
                $arr_link = (isset($id_cms) && !isset($id_cms_category)) ?
                    $link->getCMSLink($id_cms, $infos['link_rewrite'], null, $infos['id_lang']) :
                    $link->getCMSCategoryLink($id_cms_category, $infos['link_rewrite'], $infos['id_lang']);
                $default_rewrite[$infos['id_lang']] = $arr_link;
            }
        }
        $this->smarty->assign('lang_rewrite_urls', $default_rewrite);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Вопрос - чем заменить $lang_rewrite_urls.$indice_lang или как переписать, что-бы шёл вывод текущей страницы
Либо забить и через новый запрос вызывать текущую страницу

На выходе должен получить:

```
<link href="http://site.com/ru/" rel="alternate" hreflang="ru">
<link href="http://site.com/uk/" rel="alternate" hreflang="uk">
```

А выводит только альтернативную (при условии, что страница http://site.com/ru/):

```
<link href="http://site.com/uk/" rel="alternate" hreflang="uk">
```

Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Так что, светлые умы программирования, есть предложения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В результате сделал такой костыль:

```
    <link href="http://{$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST}{$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI|escape:htmlall}" rel="alternate" hreflang="{$language.iso_code|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
    /Генерация кода к текущей странице/
            {foreach from=$languages key=k item=language name="languages"}
                {if $language.iso_code != $lang_iso}
                    {assign var=indice_lang value=$language.id_lang}
                    {if isset($lang_rewrite_urls.$indice_lang)}
                        <link href="{$lang_rewrite_urls.$indice_lang|escape:htmlall}" rel="alternate" hreflang="{$language.iso_code|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
    /здесь так и не работает ссылка текущей страницы — не генерируется/
                    {else}
                        <link href="{$link->getLanguageLink($language.id_lang)|escape:htmlall}" rel="alternate" hreflang="{$language.iso_code|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
/вызов всех альтернативных страниц языков/
                    {/if}
                {/if}
                {if $language.iso_code != $lang_iso}
                {/if}
            {/foreach}
```

Нашел вот такой плагин, который более коректно выводит Hreflang
https://github.com/faktiva/prestashop-seo-tk

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант - это сделать доп проверку на текущий url. в Smarty есть переменная $smarty.get.page выводит полный урл к странице.

```
{foreach from=$languages key=k item=language name="languages"}
    {if $language.iso_code != $lang_iso}
        {assign var=indice_lang value=$language.id_lang}
        {if isset($lang_rewrite_urls.$indice_lang)}
            {if $lang_rewrite_urls.$indice_lang|escape:htmlall != $smarty.get.page }
                  <link href="{$lang_rewrite_urls.$indice_lang|escape:htmlall}" rel="alternate" hreflang="{$language.iso_code|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
           {else}
                  <p>PAGE NAME</p>
           {/if}
        {else}
             {if $link->getLanguageLink($language.id_lang)|escape:htmlall != $smarty.get.page }
                 <link href="{$link->getLanguageLink($language.id_lang)|escape:htmlall}" rel="alternate" hreflang="{$language.iso_code|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
             {else}
                <p>PAGE NAME</p>
             {/if}
        {/if}
    {/if}
    {if $language.iso_code != $lang_iso}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Так же можно попробовать вместо $smarty.get.page использовать $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI - тогда сравнение будет не с полным урлом, а его частью без доменного имени

Comment: Нет, не получается. Все равно выводит только вариант 

`<link href="{$link->getLanguageLink($language.id_lang)|escape:htmlall}" rel="alternate" hreflang="{$language.iso_code|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">`

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Сделал таким кривым костылем - перед кодом прикрутил код
`<link href="http://{$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST}{$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI|escape:htmlall}" rel="alternate" hreflang="{$language.iso_code|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">`

Answer (score 0):

Просмотрите пожалуйста, первое что выдал гугл по запросу, подошло ли?:
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/328680-hreflang-and-canonical-links-creation-on-prestashop-16/

Comment: Фактически - оно, но на практике ситуация другая. В престе уже заложен весь код, который необходим для генерации hreflang, только они не сделали сам вывод. 
Тут парень просто дописал/переписал 1-2 строки кода и хочет 15 евро.
Я вижу, что какая-то переменная здесь блокирует генерацию этой 1-й строки, но не могу дойти - какая